# Creating a local ReactJS library and importing it in another project (using npm)

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

I have created one local library project 'uilibrary' using create-react-app and importing this in another react project ('actualproject').

Both the project folders are in 'root' folder as follows:

```
root
    /uilibrary
    /actualproject
```

The uilibrary project has following structure:

```
/uilibrary
    /src
        /lib
            /TopBar
                index.js
    index.js
```

I am exporting ToolBar from /uilibrary/index.js as follows:

```
import TopBar from "./lib/TopBar";
export { TopBar };
```

In the 'actualproject' react project I have following in "package.json":

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "uilibrary": "file:../uilibrary"
  }
  ...
}
```

In the 'actualproject' importing ToolBar from uilibrary does not work:

```
import TopBar from 'uilibrary';
```

Above code gives following error:

Cannot find module: 'uilibrary'. Make sure this package is installed.

Comment: any chance that what you're looking for is `npm link`?

Comment: Yes, "npm link" should work but ideally this should work as well: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths